# Как установить winreg?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Доброго времени суток!

Не могу установить модуль winreg с помощью `pip`. Использую Python версии 3.6. 
При попытке установки winreg на экран выводится следующее сообщение:

> pip3 install winreg------
>
> could not find a version that satisfies the winreg(from version) no
>   match distribution found for winreg

Подскажите, как установить этот модуль?

Answer (score 1):

Эти ошибки часто возникают из-за того, что пакет с таким именем не находится в репозитории. Используйте команду `pip search winreg`, выберите нужный пакет и установите с помощью команды `pip install <имя_выбранного_пакета>`.

В вашем случае `winreg` в *Python 3.6* входит в состав *Python Standard Library*, то есть чтобы работать с данным модулем, достаточно сделать `import winreg`.

Comment: Спасибо,вылезло куча ошибок но модуль вроде работает.Пытаюсь вытащить ветку реестра

Comment: @ispylnev ставьте "Ответ полезен" и галочку "принять ответ", а по ошибка задавайте вопросы, и вам помогут =)

Comment: @ Lex Hobbit Я пробовал ,но у меня не достаточно "репутации" для таких действий:(